# Replacing segments from an EDI file using regex, if in comments?

Tags: sql, regex, powershell

I am trying to use powershell to remove sensitive data from a file and replace it with dummy data, but only if it's in a comment block (after `--` on a line, or between `/*` and `*/`, which can span lines)

so a dummy example would be

```
So |AAthis|ABpart|is fine, as is this -- but remove ('|AAthis|ABthisisfine|ACremovethis|ADandleavetherest', more line here,3)
```

and I'd want the replacement to be

```
So |AAthis|ABpart|is fine, as is this-- but remove ('|AATHAT|ABthisisfine|ACANDREMOVETHAT|ADandleavetherest', more line here,3)
```

In powershell regex, I've gotten close:

```
$var= "So |AAthis|ABpart|is fine, as is this -- but remove ('|AAthis|ABthisisfine|ACremovethis|ADandleavetherest', more line here,3)"

$var -replace '(.*--.*\|AAthis).*(\|.*)',  ('$1' + 'THAT' + '$2')
```

, but (a) I haven't handled the multi-line blocks yet, and there's something wrong with it being greedy and removing all the intermediate segments

```
So |AAthis|ABpart|is fine, as is this -- but remove ('|AAthisTHAT|ADandleavetherest', more line here,3)
```

Comment: It is easy to parse out comments, but if the files have any constructs construed as quotes, they have to be parsed as well. Any quotes? Also, did I read you right that comment syntax is `--` to end of line, and `/* .. */` which could span lines ?

Comment: Unsure what you mean on "constructs construed as quotes".  The example above is what I expect most will look like, where it's inside quotes and ticks.  Comment syntax: correct.  (It's SQL comments, if that helps)

Comment: Is this file is made to be parsed for keywords or syntax? You have to be able to distinguish quotes if they are parsable. Example: `If this 'is a quote' Then this 'here -- is not a comment'`

Comment: What did you find out ?

Comment: the EDI string should not have quotes in it, though obviously it can be embedded in a quote.(in the example, it's embedded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do a global find / replace on each individual item.
I.e. if you have more than 1 item, you'd have to use separate regexes.

However, you can scan for *both* types of comments `--` and `/* .. */` at
the same time.

There is a single alternation for the 2 types.
Groups 1,2 cover before / after of type `/* */`  and
groups 3,4 cover before / after of type `--`.

Only 1 set of groups will match at a time so it's just a simple catenation
of groups on the replacement.

**Note**
*You have to re-run each regex until it finds no more to replace.

That is because, it is only replacing a single instance at a time (albeit globally).

You may have more instances next to each other within the same comment.

Since a match will consume the entire comment, it has to be re-run from the

beginning until it does not find any more.*

For your example it's globally:

Find `(/\*(?:(?!\*/)[\S\s])*?)\|AAthis\|((?:(?!\*/)[\S\s])*?\*/)|(--.*?)\|AAthis\|(.*)`
Replace `$1$3|replaced|$2$4`

Explanation

```
    (                             # (1 start), /* .. */ comment
         /\*     
         (?:                           # Before
              (?! \*/ )                     # Not closure
              [\S\s]                        # Dot-all
         )*?
    )                             # (1 end)
    \|AAthis\|                    # What to find in between
    (                             # (2 start)
         (?:                           # After

              (?! \*/ )                     # Not closure
              [\S\s]                        # Dot-all
         )*?
         \*/                           # Closure
    )                             # (2 end)
 |                            # or,
    (                             # (3 start), -- line comment
         --
         .*? 
    )                             # (3 end)
    \|AAthis\|                    # What to find after -- 
    (                             # (4 start)
         .* 
    )                             # (4 end)
```

Sample input:

```
 "So |AAthis|ABpart|is fine, as is this -- but remove ('|AAthis|ABthisisfine|ACremovethis|ADandleavetherest', more line here,3)"
 "And |AAthis|ABpart|is fine, as is this /* but remove
 ('|AAthis|ABthisisfine|ACremovethis|ADandleavetherest', more line here,3)" */
```

Sample output:

```
"So |AAthis|ABpart|is fine, as is this -- but remove ('|replaced|ABthisisfine|ACremovethis|ADandleavetherest', more line here,3)"
"And |AAthis|ABpart|is fine, as is this /* but remove
('|replaced|ABthisisfine|ACremovethis|ADandleavetherest', more line here,3)" */
```

Comment: @mbourgon - be sure to vote on an answer if it was helpful towards solving your problem.

Comment: Had to change it slightly - I needed to escape a couple different characters than you did.  All good, thanks again! I used `"(\/\*(?:(?!\*\/)[\S\s])*?)(\|AA[^\|]*)([\|]+(?:(?!\*\/)[\S\s])*?\*\/)|(--.*?)(\|AA[^\|]*)([\|]+(.*))"`